# Is it possible that I can train inception-v3 model only with cpu?

Tags: tensorflow

When I try to train with my own image base on Inception-v3 as follow:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py

I get this error:

```
File "/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/flowers_train.runfiles/inception/inception_train.py", line 207, in train
    assert FLAGS.batch_size % FLAGS.num_gpus == 0, (
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

My question is "Is it possible that I can train inception-v3 model  only with cpu ?"

PS: I know if only use cpu which will spend much time than gpu therefore, I have decrease the max_steps and image data.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this stupid question by myself.
I have bought a GTX 960, thanks everyone.
My reslove step by step as follow:
http://blog.twman.org/2016/06/tensorflow.html

Comment: Good to see you resolved the problem. Please note that, pure external linked answers are treated as low quality answers and this is main reason for these posts getting deleted. To avoid this, edit your post with essential parts of solution - From Review (http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12952803)